# Google Calendar sendnotifications not working

Tags: php, wordpress, google-calendar-api

I am modifying a Wordpress plugin (gravity forms to google calendar) to add a specific attendee. The event posts to the calendar, and when I view the event, it includes the intended attendee, however, it is not sending the notification for the event to the attendee.

Here is the snippet:

```
$event->setStart($start);
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('42fjsjjpte2n7ahlld603600l4@group.calendar.google.com');
// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1);
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$optArgs = array('sendNotifications'=>true);
if (! empty($location))
$event->setLocation($location);

$ret = self::$client->insert_event($calendar_id, $event, $optArgs);
```

Can you spot what I've done wrong?